# How to change the text input value to none in this existing project upon focus, in jquery

Tags: jquery, default-value, textinput

I have this so far: http://jsfiddle.net/26eVE/4/

I want that when the user clicks on the small input field (that one with value 1 as default), the value changes from 1 to "".

EDIT: Also after the focus is not on the input (the user clicks somewhere else after clicking in the input), show the default value 1 if the user didn't type anything inside the text input, otherwise keep the input he typed in.

Comment: What do you mean by "the small input"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your html, you're missing the `=` in the class attribute.

```
 <input type="text" value="1" class="item_input" />
```

Something like this is all you need.

```
    // Remove and store on focus
    // Restore if empty on blur 
    $('.item_input')
            .focus(function(e) { 
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.data('lastValue', $this.val()).val(''); 
            })
            .blur(function(e) { 
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if($this.val()=='') $this.val($this.data('lastValue')); 
            });
```

Comment: What about after the focus effect? Can you restore the default value if the user didn't type anything in? PS: I've edited my question

Comment: There are thousands of ways to do this. Updated to add one option.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a onclick event.check it http://jsfiddle.net/26eVE/5/